# Can I install Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 and Dragon 14 professional side-by-side?

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

I wonder whether I can install Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional and Dragon 14 professional side-by-side, on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: 1/ Why would you want to? 2/ Try it and see? (I don't suppose there are many superusers who have both versions and actually tried to do so before - so you probably won't get an answer).

Comment: @DavidPostill I want to do a comparison and trying is quite tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install two Dragon versions on the same computer unless it is another language version of the exact same version. This has never been the case and probably won't be anytime soon.

Possible alternatives for testing a new Dragon version:

1. Use a different computer.
2. Dual-boot your comp.
3. Use a VM (not VirtualBox or Hyper-V, which basically leaves VMWare).
4. Uninstall old version (1. Export words with properties & commands, then user profile, 2. Use Dragon removal tool, 3. install new version. 4. import Words and commands, 5. try new version. If OK, leave as is. If not, uninstall new Dragon, use removal tool for the new version, install old version, restore user profile).

Comment: Thanks. Why not VirtualBox?

Comment: @franck You can try, but last time I checked - a few months ago - It garbled the voice input to the VM. Codec or driver issue, I guess. Dragon is not usable like that. You can get a trial version of VMWare Player for 30 days.